# IF THEN ELSE nested statement system dynamics command in NetLogo

Tags: if-statement, netlogo, systemdynamics

I have variables in system dynamic in NetLogo and I am trying a nested if else as follows

```
Md * (( ifelse n_porg = 0 [ 0 ] [ ifelse ( ( SDIa * Total_norg ) / n_porg ) > 1 
       [ 1 ] [ ( SDIa * Total_norg ) / n_porg ] ] ) / delay )
```

I am getting an error "`Expected reporter`" please help

Answer (score 4):

`ifelse` is a command; you can't drop a command into the middle of a reporter expression, because a command doesn't report a value.

Instead of `ifelse`, use `ifelse-value`, which is a reporter.

You may find you need to add parentheses, e.g. `ifelse (n_porg = 0) ...`